# Classifiers which only answer when they are confident?

Tags: classification, references, uncertainty

It is often true that a classifier (or regression) can give some kind of confidence in its answers, e.g. through bootstrapping.  However, this is often viewed as an afterthought: "here is the answer, here is how confident I am in it."

I am interested in a classifier which, when given an example, will determine how confident it is in its own prediction as a more fundamental part of the process.

Specifically, when judging the effectiveness of the classifier, one should judge (a) on what percentage of the test set is it reasonably confident, and (b) on those examples where it is confident, what is its accuracy?

(and perhaps similar for regression models)

I have some ideas how this could be done, but first I want to know if this idea has some precedence in the literature.  I don't want to reinvent the wheel!  But lots of searching has not produced any useful results.

Comment: Logistic regression does this, by giving you $Pr (y =1|x) $.  You then decide two cut-offs: high enough for it likely to be $y=1$ and low enough for it likely to be $y=0$.  In between the two cut-offs is where you aren't sure.

Comment: To some extent that's true, but then we typically measure the success of logistic regression by its classification accuracy.  I'm more looking for a general concept of how to rate these classifiers based on the two criteria stated in the question, and where/whether it's been studied specifically in the past.

Comment: @RichardRast You want a measure of model calibration. For example, Brier score or log-likelihood -- both will penalize models which produce, e.g., predictions of 0.51, but reward models which produce predictions of 0.99 for y=1 (and penalize models which predict 0.99 for y=0).